# Django- Try sending email in python shell using send_mail(), but cannot work

Tags: django, email

I am trying to send account activation link in my Django project, but it cannot work. So I try the very basic send_mail() function in shell and see if it is sending.

in the settin.py

```
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', # necessary for django.auth
    'survey.modelbackend.EmailBackend' # custom backend to authenticate using the email field
)

    #settings for the email 
    EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
    EMAIL_PORT = 25
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
```

(I am using all the default values in the settings for email)

in the shell I typed

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ...     ['myemailaddress@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

and it return 1 after the above line, but I cannot get the email in my own email

Can anyone help with this problem and explain why the email is not sent to my email?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you configure the mail server on localhost to relay email?

Comment: Have you configured an SMTP server?

Comment: hy..thanks for replying,I've just got the answer and it is posted below, may I ask what do you mean by SMTP server setting? sorry a bit new to this ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy, I've tried asking and this can successfully send email without any setting in the settings.py

first, add these two imports

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText as text
```

then the code to send email could be like this

```
def send_email(sender,receiver,message,subject):
    sender = sender
    receivers = receiver
    m = text(message)
    m['Subject'] = subject
    m['From'] = sender
    m['To'] = receiver

   # message = message

    try:
       smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
       smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, str(m))
       print "Successfully sent email"
    except SMTPException:
       print "Error: unable to send email"
```

This works just as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go ahead and say that the mail is probably being sent, but it is hitting your spam filter.

Unless you have something other than `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` set as your `settings.EMAIL_BACKEND`, you will only get a return of `True` (or `1`) if the backend has successfully connected to the server and told the server to send the message. If `fail_silently=False`, that means that `send_mail` will either return `True` or raise an exception. This means that the error either lies in your SMTP or it is being sent directly to "spam".

But, in the off chance that you have already checked spam, there are ways to make an SMTP server fail silently. Check out this article for [Sendmail](http://benoit808.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/disabling-relay-for-localhost-smtp-server-sendmail-on-linux/) (one of the most common `*nix` applications), or [this one for Mercury](https://www.zoe.vc/2008/mercury-mail-transport-system-fur-externe-mail-konfigurieren/) (one of the SMTP servers available for Windows). If you're using IIS, [this site](http://forums.iis.net/p/1157046/1901343.aspx) looks like it addresses some potential issues.